# Redirect user from controller to another view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, controller, actionresult

I'm trying to redirect a user from a method on a controller to another view but can't get it to work no matter what I do.  What am I doing wrong?  Here's my code:

```
            public ActionResult SubmitReport(string JsonStringSend)
        {
            dynamic JSend = JObject.Parse(JsonStringSend);
            var schema = JsonSchema4.FromType<ReportItem>();
            var schemaData = schema.ToJson();
            var errors = schema.Validate(JSend.JsonString);
            schema = JsonSchema4.FromJson(schemaData);


            //Check for errors and show them if they exist
            if (errors.Count > 0)
            {
                //JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(schema);
                foreach (var error in errors)
                    Console.WriteLine(error.Path + ": " + error.Kind);

                //JObject JsonString = JObject.Parse(JsonObj.JsonString.ToString());
                //JObject JsonStringSent = JObject.Parse(JsonStringSend);

            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/Admin/Reporting/ReportManagement");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

It never redirects.  I've even tried these:

```
Response.Redirect(Url.Action("/ReportManagement"));
RedirectToRoute(new { contoller = "ReportManagement", action = "Reporting" });
return RedirectToRoute(new { contoller = "Reporting", action = "ReportManagement" });
return RedirectToAction("ReportManagement");
```

Nothing seems to redirect, what gives?

Comment: If you step through the code in debug mode, what happens?

Comment: Nothing, when I get to `return Redirect("/Admin/Reporting/ReportManagement");` it just keeps on stepping

Comment: What's your current URL?

Comment: https://plus.inroll.com/Admin/Reporting/EditReport

Comment: the return RedirectToAction("Whatever") should respond to your browser with a 302 response and make the browser request the "Whatever" URL.  That's really strange.  You could probably fire up Fiddler and see what response is coming back, if any.

Comment: Maybe it's due to the ajax call to the method?  Don't know why, but this is weird.

Comment: I think it's because of the AJAX.  Put the redirect in the success() method. `$.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (d) {
                    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
                }
            });`

Comment: I can't do that because it it will always success, I'm doing logic in the controller and if true, redirect and if false, display modal.

Comment: Then, return a value from the `SubmitReport` action that can be evaluated on Ajax success: `function(d) { if (d.valid) { location.href = redirectUrl; } else { //invalid flow } }`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't redirect to a view, you redirect to an action or a route. If I'm correctly parsing the path you're attempting, where you have this:

```
return Redirect("/Admin/Reporting/ReportManagement")
```

should be

```
return RedirectToAction("Reporting", "ReportManagement", new { area="Admin" })
```

This assumes a *Reporting* action on a *ReportManagementController* class in the *Admin* area.

Comment: Thank you for showing the route value params for "Areas." Big help!

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it should be work:

```
return RedirectToAction("yourAnotherActionName","yourAnotherControllerName"); //It's very simply;)
```

I've tested it!